# One word for either Income (credit) or Expense (debit)

Tags: single-word-requests, business-language

What word better denotes a money transaction: debit or credit?

Comment: What's wrong with with *transaction*?

Comment: Transaction is too general. I am looking for something specific to money.

Comment: Transaction has taken on some additional meanings, but the original meaning was business dealings and the records of business dealings. Unless used with a specifically non-monetary context most people will assume a financial meaning. Entries in a ledger are called a transaction, whether they are a credit or a debit. Bank statements and check registers use the term as well.

Comment: Depends if your an accountant or not.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debits_and_credits#Terminology

Answer (score -1):

Pecuniary - (adjective)

1. consisting of or measured in money
2. of or relating to money

www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pecuniary

You could say a pecuniary transaction or pecuniary trade or pecuniary barter /dealing.

You could also use financial, fiscal or monetary in place of pecuniary. The definition is from Merriam Webster.

Comment: Will the veteran who downvoted venture to talk?

Answer (score -1):

Disbursement--the act of disbursing;(or) funds paid out. (see also disburse(vt); disbursed; disbursing; disburser.

to Disburse--to pay out, esp. from a fund; to make a payment in settlement of obligation, debt, will, etc.